# how to use mod_rewrite on a file in a folder?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make this url:

> `http://jawapa.bl.ee/ee/profiles/index.html?/jawapa`

look like this:

> `http://jawapa.bl.ee/ee/profiles/?/jawapa`

I have tried several different options and none of them worked. Someone suggested looking into `mod_rewrite`. I did and came up with the following:

```
RewriteEngine on RewriteRule .* /ee/profiles/index.html
```

I'm not familiar with `mod_rewrite` at all, so I'm clueless as to why this isn't working. After looking into it a bit more, I keep seeing references to a file called `httpd.conf`. I don't see that file on my system anywhere. Is this something I can just create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in `/ee/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ee/

RewriteRule ^profiles/?$ profiles/index.html [L]
```

Comment: Ah thank you! I was not aware that you could add your own .htaccess in another folder.